# regex to match last 3 strings

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I am new to using regular expressions so please pardon me. I need to match only the town, region name and country name using regex. Below is the sample from the dataset I have

```
1 Cliff Street ; Fremantle, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
10 Montpelier Square, London SW7 1JU ;,; UNITED KINGDOM
125 Hay Street ; East Perth, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
1395 Brickell Ave 3404, Miami, FL 33131 ;,; USA
14 Save Ljuboje ; Banja Luka,; BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA
15 Grosvenor Street ; Beaconsfield, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
151 Royal Street, 2nd Floor ; East Perth, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
168-170 St Georges Terrace ; Perth, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
184 Bennet Street ; East Perth, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
189 Royal Street ; East Perth, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
197 St Georges Terrace ; Perth, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA
```

Example: `1 Cliff Street ; Fremantle, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA` I would want only `Fremantle, Western Australia ; AUSTRALIA` and not the address tags along. This is just a sample of my dataset and I would want only the last 3 strings in each row. It would be great if anyone could help me

Comment: Split on `;` if the fields are fixed. Otherwise you'd have to use some international post address parsing software.

Comment: Which programming are you using down under?

Comment: Entries like `10 Montpelier Square, London SW7 1JU ;,; UNITED KINGDOM` make me think that a simple SO regex might not be best solution if you're talking about parsing a large number of records...

Comment: @jan I am using sublime text to remove the address specifics like apartment no. so that I have only the city and location names and not street addresses. There are a few records without street addresses also in my dataset and I don't want to remove anything from them

Comment: @sln  I am using sublime text to remove the address specifics like apartment no. so that I have only the city and location names and not street addresses. There are a few records without street addresses also in my dataset and I don't want to remove anything from them

Answer (score 0):

You could use capturing groups for this...

[`(.*);(.*);(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nG5dZ0/1)

That regex splits the string into 3 groups.  How you access the groups from the match object depends on your language's regex library.

---

As @sin suggested, a better approach would probably be just splitting the string on `;` character.  Just google for "String Splitting" to see how it is done in your language.  Using regexes overcomplicates this problem.

Comment: This is **very** inefficient. Make yourself aware how a regex engine works: it encounters the pattern `.*` which *brings you down the line and then backtracks*. This is done three times per line in your example. **Please be more specific** and try to say what you actually want: not a `;` - then say it: [`^([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/nG5dZ0/2). Yours: **1512** steps, mine **666**, a reduction by more than the half.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match them use this regex:

```
[1-9a-zA-Z\s,]+;[1-9a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cF1gW4/1

**EDIT**

If you want to leave them and remove first part of the address, using SublimeText replace this:

```
^[1-9a-zA-Z\s,]+;\s?
```

by nothing

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cF1gW4/3